# What is an anisotropic cost-of-passage map called in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, cost-path

I am trying to make sense of a few sources of information.
In *Geographic Information Systems in Archaeology* Conolly and Lake (2006: 214-224)
provide a sort of "step-by-step" procedure for creating accurate LCP models.  However they do not advocate using ArcGIS, which is what I am stuck with.

They say: cost-passage-map > accumulated cost surface > LCP algorithm.
That is all well and good but these terms are different in ArcGIS 10.1 and I am not sure which I should be using.
For example, in ArcGIS the Path Distance function provides a 'spreading function' over a cost surface map, but according to Conolly and Lake a cost surface IS the spreading function.  Any clarity would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The similar model in ArcGIS is Path Distance and Cost Path. Path distance corresponds to accumulated cost surface while Cost path corresponds to LCP algorithm. So you only need to provide the cost surface.